# batch file to copy a file to local folder from the web

Tags: batch-file, web, hyperlink, copy

Can i put a link on our website that is a batch file written to copy a file into a local folder when the link is clicked on? our users need a file copied to their machine from our website..basically an update.

Answer (score 1):

No, due to standard browser security restrictions the best you can provide is a link to the file for the user to download. A "Save As" dialog will appear and the actual download location will be up to the user.

You have no control over where the user will download the file to.